# Does PowerShell provide a way to create function annotations?

Tags: powershell

*EDITED to reduce confusion on the intended aim*

Is it possible to create any sort of annotation which can apply a common pattern to a function?

An example may be a standard error-handling routine. Rather than having to implement the same try/catch structure with the error-handling function, it would be nice to have an attribute or annotation with which I could decorate the function, thus implementing the common pattern without using the same explicit code in each function.

Perhaps this is a case of trying to shoehorn PowerShell into doing something it isn't meant to do, but I'd like to avoid some of the repetition I find most common in my scripts.

Comment: There is `[ValidateScript()]`. [Here's a guide for ValidateScript](https://powershell.org/2013/05/21/validatescript-for-beginners/) and here is [Boe Prox's guide to parameter validation](https://learn-powershell.net/2014/02/04/using-powershell-parameter-validation-to-make-your-day-easier/) with some of the other validation methods like ValidatePattern that may also fit

Comment: The reference to parameter validation attributes was more of a nod towards the way I'd like to decorate functions which references existing PowerShell functionality. In retrospect, I probably should have stuck with mentioning annotations, as implementing common patterns is more the thrust of my interest.

Comment: It seems like you're asking about function-level attributes, similar to [CmdletBinding()].

Comment: @MilesGrimes - Did you ever come across a solution? I find myself in the same position you were in with repeating try/catch structures all over the place.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I did not find a solution for my use case :(

Answer (score 5):

You just need to inherit from `ValidateArgumentsAttribute` class and provide custom validation logic in `Validate` method:
C#:

```
Add-Type @‘
    using System;
    using System.Management.Automation;
    public class ValidateIsEvenAttribute : ValidateArgumentsAttribute {
        protected override void Validate(object arguments, EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics) {
            if(LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo<int>(arguments)%2==1) {
                throw new Exception("Not even");
            }
        }
    }
’@
```

PowerShell v5:

```
class ValidateIsOddAttribute : Management.Automation.ValidateArgumentsAttribute {
    [void] Validate([object] $arguments, [Management.Automation.EngineIntrinsics] $engineIntrinsics) {
        if($arguments%2-eq0) {
            throw 'Not odd'
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can apply that attributes to function parameters:

```
function f { param([ValidateIsEven()]$i, [ValidateIsOdd()] $j) $i, $j }

f 2 1 #OK
f 2 2 #Error
f 1 1 #Error
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a good answer as it comes to parameter attributes. I've modified the question to clarify, as I'm not so much trying to decorate parameters as I am looking to implement common patterns in functions without rewriting similar code.